# VBA use for each loop to divide through a range

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I have a range of values (estimated project hours) and I have a status cell (total estimated project hours. I have date columns that are being generated with vba as well. Essentially, I want to divide each cell in the range by the status total estimated hours cell, and repeat the value across that row for each date (giving estimated hours per week). After that row is complete, I want to drop to the next cell in the range and repeat the process.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub headers()
    Dim start As Double
    Dim weeks As Integer

    start = Range("B1").Value
    weeks = Range("B3").Value
    For i = 0 To weeks - 1
        Cells(8, 5 + i).Value = start + 4 + (i * 7)
    Next

End Sub


Sub PopulateValues()
    Dim weeks As Integer
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    weeks = Range("B3").Value
    resources = Range("B6").Value
    Set rRng = Range("D9:D50")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells

        If IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then Exit For

        For i = 0 To weeks - 1
            Cells(9, 5 + i).Value = rCell.Value / weeks
        Next
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

What it's doing is looping through the range but it's doing all of the division on the same row, never iterating down to the next row.

Any help would be lovely.

Thanks in advance.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6dxa9ethbsix58/VBA.PNG?dl=0

Comment: for this part `Cells(9, 5 + i).Value = rCell.Value / weeks` since you don't ever change the "9" won't it always be filling in cells in row 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your for loop you have  Cells(9, 5 + i).Value. The variable in this is the "i" for the columns.

You need another variable 
   For Each rCell In rRng.Cells

```
    If IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then Exit For
    For j = 0 to weeks - 1
        For i = 0 To weeks - 1
            Cells(9+j, 5 + i).Value = rCell.Value / weeks
        Next
    Next
Next rCell
```

It will start with the first row, 9 (9 + j = 9), and after it runs through all columns (i), it will go to the next j ( row 10).

Comment: Hi @Rossle, thanks for the input. However, using that code, these are the results I'm getting:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8dstyyyvh5xf5g/VBA%201.PNG?dl=0

These are the desired results: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/frshel1l1r5umdz/VBA%202.PNG?dl=0

Essentially, each row should be a repeating value of Estimated Project Hours / 7. Example: Row 9 = 200 / 7; Row 10 = 90 / 7, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to open your files at work. The code I added was more of an example, and maybe not packaged and ready to go. Maybe tonight when I am at home I can look at your file. In the mean time, if it were me I would execute the code one line at a time with F8, and look at every single variable as it executes. From there you can see how it is determining where to write each value.

Comment: No worries @rossle. I was able to figure it out. I had one too many loops in the code that was causing it to overwrite.

Comment: Cool, glad you were able to figure it out.